# How to get all elements on same row html css

Tags: html, css

My screen looks like this:
[image]

I want everything to be on the same row. How do I fix this? My html code:

```
  .form-box
      %h3 Restrictions
      %legend Restricted Locations
      %fieldset.restrictions-row
        .restrictions-row.restrictions-label
          = label_tag :us_states, "US States"
        .restrictions-row.restrictions-select
          = collection_select :restriction, :category, Restriction.where(category: "US State"), :id, :name, prompt: true
          = hidden_field_tag :product_id, @wine.product.id
          = hidden_field_tag :restriction_category, "US State"
        .restrictions-row
          = button_tag "Add", class: 'btn btn-primary'
        %table.table.table-hover.table-condensed.story-list.restrictions-row
          %th{ style: 'padding: 3% 17%' } State
          %th{ style: 'padding: 3% 17%'} Remove
```

my css:

```
  .restrictions-label {
    width: 10%;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .restrictions-select {
    width: 10%;
  }
  .restrictions-row {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

What is taking precedence? why isn't border-line working when I apply it to the divs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `inline-block` to all the elements you need to run inline, not just on the parent. The table for example, is by default `display: table`. You need to make that `inline-block`, also.

```
.table {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: .restrictions-row class is on table so it should be already displayed inline block. Someone may think about override in this case but since it is last class written on table it should override default

Answer (score 0):

```
fieldset.restrictions-row > .restrictions-row{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
```

this is the code works like you mentioned at usual cases.

In case you fail to accomplish by code above you can use float. Then by using after you can clear float

```
fieldset.restrictions-row > .restrictions-row{
  float:left;
}
fieldset.restrictions-row::after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear: both;
}
```